# Determining the line number of a combination from a sorted text file

Tags: combinations

Uppercase letters $(A - Z)$ and numbers $(0 - 9)$ are used to generate all possible combinations of strings of length $10$ characters such as $NAH562GTDS$. Assuming that all the possible combinations are generated and sorted in a text file such that the very first string is $0000000000$ and the last one $ZZZZZZZZZZ$, how can we determine the line number in which a string appears?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Think to the given string as number written in base $10+26$.

P.S. In this base what is the numerical value of the digits $Y$, $E$ and $S$? Then what is the position of the string $0000000YES$? Show your effort and edit your question with your attempt.

Comment: Apologies good sir, but could you please elaborate further with an example?

Comment: In this base what is the numerical value of the digits $Y$, $E$ and $S$? Then what is the position of the string $0000000YES$? Show your effort and edit your question with your attempt.

Comment: I have no effort whatsoever. My mind is an enigma that just comes up with these ideas from nowhere. When that happens, I am completely at lost on what to do. This is one of those instances.

Comment: This page could be useful: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal_numeral_system

Comment: Why hexadecimal? That doesn't look like what I'm looking for

Comment: Not exactly, but it is the same idea, in your case we have 36 digits instead of 16.

Comment: Okay so the values of Y, E,and S are 34, 14 and 28 respectively. Using an online converter to convert 341428 from base 36 to decimal gives me 188168912. This can't be right, right?

Comment: The values for the digits are correct. The number for YES is $34*36^2+14*36+28=44596$.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now. Indeed, after generating SOME of the combinations, 0000000YES appears at line number 44, 597. I just have to perform a "+1" to your solution.

Comment: Yes, you have to shift by $1$ since the number $0$ is at the $1$st  position.